# I have two papers in an up-coming conference. Is it appropriate to cite one in another?

Tags: conference, citations

I had two papers approved for a workshop in a IEEE conference and I'm going to send the camera-ready version soon.

Is it OK to have one paper cite the other? If it's OK, do I have to reference the other paper as "to appear"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is acceptable, and fairly common. You cite as usual, and the citation itself would be identical to a standard citation with the exception that the date and page numbers would be replaced by the phrase "in press".

From the [American Historical Association's "Professional Standards" page](http://www.historians.org/PUBS/Free/ProfessionalStandards.cfm#Reputation):

> The AHA suggests the following lexicon.
>
> - "In Press": the manuscript is fully copyedited and out of the author's hands. It is in the final stages of the production process.
> - "Forthcoming": a completed manuscript has been accepted by a press or journal.
> - "Under contract to . . .": a press and an author have signed a contract for a book in progress, but the final manuscript has not yet been submitted.
> - "Submitted" or "under consideration": the book or article has been submitted to a press or journal, but there is as yet no contract or agreement to publish.

Comment: That's right, [IEEE also suggests "in press"](ftp://pubftp.computer.org/press/outgoing/proceedings/instruct6x9.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

It is okay for each paper to cite the other.

It would be better if more accurate publication details were given. Sometimes the published will add this information (this happens at Springer for LNCS volumes). Perhaps you can alert the editor of the fact, and they might be able to make sure that you have the right information for the citation or they can ensure that the publishers do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's fine.  I would probably cite it as follows:

> First Author and Second Author.  This is the title of this paper, which is also found several times in the paper itself.  These *Proceedings*, 2013.

Comment: it is better to avoid citing as "These proceedings" or similar formulation, I'll explain why:) The problem is that this reads nicely for a human being, but when processed by various citation services (e.g., Scopus, Google Scholar) will not necessarily be resolved correctly. Therefore, it is always better to be specific about which proceedings/issue you refer to.

Comment: @al_b The expectation is that it would be replaced with the appropriate citation at the time of typesetting - when the exact data (incl. page numbers) would be known for the other publication.

Comment: @Peteris This is not a reasonable expectation.  In my field, papers are typeset _by their authors_ (via LaTeX), often months before page numbers are known.

Comment: "These proceedings" is likely to persevere till the final version, since the publisher might ignore your request to correct it. This method is not good.

Comment: Why should the publisher correct it? It’s already correct!

Comment: Because it's **not a full bibliographic reference**. Moreover, it's void of meaning if the paper is read standalone and the proceedings are not mentioned there otherwise.

Comment: I agree with @al_b Automatic recognition of the source won't be possible.