# How do I cite an unpublished work in my paper? which incidentally is my second submission to the same conference

Tags: citations, writing

The problem is I completed a work earlier and did another work which extends this work. However, I haven't got the earlier work published. I plan to send these two papers to a conference but I do not know how to cite the work of first paper in second paper.

Comment: The last point of [eykanal's answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/8446/102) seems to answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many people, including myself, use the following style:

> Author. “Paper Title,” manuscript, year.
>
> e.g.:
>   [13] A.N. Author, “Paper Citation Rules,” manuscript, 2013.

If it's your paper you can also cite it as

> Author. “Paper Title,” submitted, year.

The proper citation style may depend on the conference you submit your paper to. In my area, theoretical computer science, there are no strict citation rules.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know or have information about the writing style or style guide that is usually followed in your field and you should follow those style guides to find out how to cite unpublished works .

To get you kickstarted in the right direction, I have provided information about the [APA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APA_style), [Chicago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicago_Manual_of_Style) and [MLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_MLA_Style_Manual) styles and how to cite unpublished works. Of course, your field may use completely unrelated style guides but they should have typical information for unpublished works. See [this](http://linguistics.byu.edu/faculty/henrichsenl/apa/APA14.html), [this](http://nova.campusguides.com/content.php?pid=114919&sid=992797), [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_2315829_cite-unpublished-sources-chicago-manual.html) and [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_4450351_cite-unpublished-work-mla-format.html) for more information.